# Disable landscape mode in Blackberry phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I am developing a Blackberry app using Phonegap. In this how can I disable landscape mode and allow only portrait mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the config file and add the code below

```
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

And to detail you may be look the

http://cmer.uoguelph.ca/freshlabs/Lab5A.pdf

Comment: Is it for Blackberry? I included in config.xml but is not working. Can you please tell me where exactly to include this?

Comment: Another question asked in https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/2T7CUlZDy9g    and that may help you.

Answer (score 3):

Add the below code in your config file:-

```
<feature id="blackberry.app" >      
        <param name="orientation" value="portrait" />  
    </feature>
```

Hope this helps.